# Node data retrieval for different language

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have two languages (English [en] and Arabic [ar]) setup in Drupal 8.3 CMS. I am trying to retrieve data with Node using API, based on the user input language parameter. When I print the node data by default I get result in English language. What will be the simplest way to get result in Arabic?

I am using the following function to get the details from DB.

```
    $node_type = $response['course_type'];

    $nids  = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', $node_type)->execute();
    $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);

    foreach ($nodes as $key => $item) {

        $dish_title                                            = $item->title->value;
        $response['get_courses']['dishes'][]                   = trim($dish_title);
        $response['get_courses'][$dish_title]['dish_image'][]  = trim("upcoming");
        $response['get_courses'][$dish_title]['course_name'][] = trim($item->getType());
        $response['get_courses'][$dish_title]['description'][] = trim($item->body->value);
        $response['get_courses'][$dish_title]['dish_name'][]   = trim($dish_title);

}
```

Please refer the following link for the result array.
http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0D7TT6

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `->getTranslation()` on the node:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node = $node->getTranslation($langcode);
  // get the field values from the translated node
  $field_example_value_translated = $node->field_example->value;
}
```